# Chip rate and sample rate

Tags: sampling, digital-communications

If a sequence of +1 and -1 with chip rate ($\frac{1}{0.57 ns}$) is being used for purpose of estimating channel impulse response with delay spread of 6ns.

We decide to have a new rate change to rate $\frac{1}{0.38 ns} $. Then in the digital domain we upsample by 3 the initial signal, filter than downsample by 2  and we have a new sequence with new chip rate.

My question is, given the fact that the to *sequence length should be longer than maximum length of channel impulse response to estimate CIF accurately* in this case $6 ns$. What is the number of chips that is required for best estimation?

There are two possible answers:

1) Minimum number of chips * 0.57 $\geq 6 $

2) Minimum number of chips * 0.38 $\geq 6 $

I think the correct answer is 2, what do you think?

Thanks.